# What are the best practices for designing function templates to deal with string/char arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to write a simple string `split` function.

The function should take one `std::basic_string` and a delimiter (possibly a `CharT` or `std::basic_string`), and put the result into a `ContainerT`.

My first try is

```
template <typename StringT, typename DelimiterT, typename ContainerT>
void split(
    const StringT &str, const DelimiterT &delimiters, ContainerT &conts) {
    conts.clear();
    std::size_t start = 0, end;
    std::size_t len = delimiters.size();
    while ((end = str.find(delimiters, start)) != StringT::npos) {
        if (end - start) {
            conts.emplace_back(str, start, end - start);
        }
        start = end + len;
    }

    if (start != StringT::npos && start < str.size()) {
        conts.emplace_back(str, start, str.size() - start);
    }
}
```

My final goal is to extend this function to achieve:

1. The final results are always `std::basic_string<CharT>` put into some `conts`.
2. The first argument `str` could be `std::basic_string<CharT>`, `const CharT*` or a string literal.
3. The second argument `delimiter` could be a `char`, or a `std::basic_string<CharT>`/`const CharT*`/string literal, meaning that the length of the delimiter is greater than 1, e.g. split `aaa,,bbb,c` with `,,` gives `aaa/bbb,c`.
4. The third argument can be any sequence container from `STL`.

Since one usually deals with modern stings in C++, 2 may be `std::basic_string<CharT>` only for simplification.

Given that the function (template) can be overloaded, I wonder

1. At least how many functions would I need in this situation?
2. And what's the best practice to design such functions(How to write more generic functions)? For example, maybe to make the above function work with a `const CharT*` delimiter, the line `std::size_t len = delimiters.size();` must be changed to some `std::distance(...)`?

Update:

A revalent code review is added [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195253/template-function-for-splitting-strings-in-c).

Comment: I find this tricky because of all the potential combinations. I have tried many approaches. The current one I use has a **master** template function taking only iterators for the input string and for the delimiters (four iterators s_begin, s_end, d_begin, d_end). Then I have a whole lot of different overloads that  convert their input parameters into that most basic form.

Comment: Have you seen the top answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::string_view` for both text to be split and delimeter. Additionally, you can use template template parameter to choose type of elements in the result:

```
template<typename Char, template<typename> class Container, typename String>
Container<String> split_impl(std::basic_string_view<Char> text, std::basic_string_view<Char> delim)
{
    Container<String> result;
    //...
    result.push_back(String(text.substr(start, count)));
    //...
    return result;
}

template<template<typename> class Container, typename String = std::string_view>
Container<String> split(std::string_view text, std::string_view delim)
{ return split_impl<char, Container, String>(text, delim); }

template<template<typename> class Container, typename String = std::u16string_view>
Container<String> split(std::u16string_view text, std::u16string_view delim)
{ return split_impl<char16_t, Container, String>(text, delim); }
```

This way, it can be used with `std::string`, `std::string_view` and `const char*` without redundant allocations:

```
// vector of std::string_view objects:
auto words_1 = split<std::vector>("hello world", " ");

// list of std::string objects:
auto words_2 = split<std::list, std::string>(std::string("hello world"), " ");

// vector of std::u16string_view objects:
auto words_3 = split<std::vector>(u"hello world", u" ");
```

**Edit:** added overloads for `char` and `char16_t`

**Edit 2**

In code above, `split_impl` does actual work. `split` overloads are provided only to simplify user code, so that you don't have to explicitly specify character type to be used. It would be necessary without overloads, because compiler can't deduce `Char` when type of parameter is `basic_string_view` and you're passing an argument of different type (for example, `const char*` or `std::wstring`). In general, I think it isn't a big problem - probably, you want to have four overloads (`char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`), if not less.

However, for completeness, here's an alternative that doesn't use overloads:

```
template<typename ContainerT, typename TextT, typename DelimT>
ContainerT split(const TextT& text, const DelimT& delim)
{
    using CharT = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text[0])>;

    std::basic_string_view<CharT> textView(text);
    std::basic_string_view<CharT> delimView(delim);

    ContainerT result;

    // actual implementation, but using textView and delimView instead of text and delim

   result.push_back(textView.substr(start, count));

   return result;
}

// usage:
auto words = split<std::vector<std::string_view>>("some text", " ");
```

With this approach you cannot use default value of `String` template parameter, as above (because it would have to depend on `TextT` type). For this reason, I removed it. Also, this code assumes that `text` and `delim` use the same character type and can be converter to `basic_string_view`.

Personally, I prefer version 1. It doesn't use template types for function parameters, which is IMHO better, as it gives caller better idea about what should be passed in. In other words, interface of the first `split` is better specified. Also, as noted above, I don't consider having to add four overloads of `split` a problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This version seems not care for `wstring/u16string/u32string`. While `string` can be converted to `string_view` implicitly, `basic_string<T>` seems can not be converted `basic_string_view<T>` when doing template argument deduction.

Comment: I've updated answer to include overloads for char and char16_t. I think that solves the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to merge these `char/wchar_t/char16_t...` in some way?

Comment: Updated again with one way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Construct `basic_string_view` from the input strings, then operate on those. A `basic_string_view` has an explicit constructor taking a `char*`, and `basic_string` has a cast operator to `basic_string_view`.

Comment: Should one use some `std::basic_string_view<CharT>` as template function parameter? It seems that if passing a `std::string` it can't be converted implicitly which seems lose some convenience when passing parameters.

Comment: `std::string` has a conversion operator for converting to `std::string_view` so this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be to use a two template parameters one for input string and one for output container, because in almost all cases, input string, deliminator and output container will be of same type so you can define your function something like this -

```
template<typename charT, typename Container)
void split(const std::basic_string<charT> input,
    const charT deliminator,
    Container<std::basic_string<chart>> &cont)
```

for 2nd scenario your deliminator can be of `std::basic_string<charT>` type.